# ngOnInit not called when navigating to route parameter

Tags: angular, ngoninit

I've been having this issue for a while now with every version of Angular I've used, but have fudged my way around it (currently on 6.0.3). I've got routes setup like this:

```
/book/:param
```

And I'm reading the parameter in ngOnInit fine, I can display it in the template etc. After that I have a quick way of setting a pretty version of the parameter which I actually want to display but this is never updated after the first time either route is navigated to. The same goes for anything I do differently for each route.

Should I just make separate components instead of using parameters or am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 2):

No need to write routing configuration like this -

```
/book/:all
/book/:notconfirmed
```

Just replace this with a single line like this -

```
/book/:flag
```

Now what you have to do is, Just subscribe to `params` coming from routing and do whatever you want to do.

```
this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
   console.log('every time route params chnages you will get here');
}
```

Comment: My bad, it's just one parameter but those are the two different sub pages I'm using. Editing the original question.